# Firebase user authentication with AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to authenticate the user through Github using AngularFire but I keep getting the error:

> ref.authWithOAuthPopup is not a function

This is my controller code:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<MY-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
    function authHandler(error, authDat) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload: ", authData);
        }
    }
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("github", authHandler);
}]);
```

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle or jsbin to reproduce this, along with details on which version of AngularFire you're using?

Comment: I dont think I'm allowed to create a jsfiddle for my project but my angularfire version is 0.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using an older version or firebase itself ... I was using version 1.0.18 while the current version is 2.2.9.